# How relation can be made of parent and child from one "user" table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, recursion, parent-child, database-normalization

I'm making an school management system , I m told just to make one "user" table instead of making different tables of student, parent and teacher. I m confused how can I register student with relation of his parent .I m creating this project using Laravel framework 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Well, to link an object of an A class to a parent of the same class (A) you just need to set it in an attribute:

**`students` table schema**

```
id
parent_id // <--- this is the key.
name
...

/**
* this addional (and optional) attribute can help you to identify
* if this is the parent of the branch, because with
* this approach you can have grandchilds and so on..
**/
is_root // <---
```

Then in your model:

**User.php**

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Now, regarding the type of user, you can also set an attribute to know the user type:

```
id
parent_id
name
type // <-- this could show the user type: 'student', 'teacher', etc
```